# Relationship Between Fourier Cosine/Sine Transforms and Fourier Transforms

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, fourier-analysis

Here we denote the Fourier transform as $$F(k)=\mathcal{F}(f(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)e^{-ikx} \ dx,$$ and the Fourier cosine transform and Fourier sine transform as 
\begin{align}
F_c(k)=\mathcal{F}(f(x))&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty} f(x) \cos(kx)  \ dx \\ 
F_s(k)=\mathcal{F}(f(x))&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty} f(x) \sin(kx)  \ dx 
\end{align} respectively.

If we are trying to determine the Fourier cosine transform of an even function, $\text{e.g}  \ \  \mathcal{F}_c\left(e^{-k^2t}\right),$ is this identical to the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}\left(e^{-k^2t}\right)$? If this is true, can a similar argument be made for odd functions involving the Fourier sine transform?

Update:

Proof for Fourier cosine:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}(f(x))&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)e^{-ikx} \ dx \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\left(\cos(kx)-i\sin(kx)\right) \ dx \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\cos(kx) \ dx-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\sin(kx) dx \\
&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty} f(x) \cos(kx)  \ dx \tag{1} \\
&=\mathcal{F}_c(f(x)).
\end{align}
Is my proof correct? In line $(1)$, I defined $f(x)$ to be an even function. Following on from this proof, this would seem to indicate that if $f(x)$ is odd, then $\mathcal{F}(f(x))=-i\mathcal{F}_s(f(x))$. This doesn't seem consistent with my previous intuition.

Comment: Is there a typo? Shouldn't $\mathcal{F}_c\left(e^{-k^2t}\right)$ be $\mathcal{F}_c\left(e^{-a x^2}\right)$ or something that's not already in the frequency space?

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I don't think so. This post was prompted by solving the heat equation via a Fourier cosine transform with respect to $x$. What you have suggested may be in terms of notation, but I'm more concerned with understanding the relationship of the Fourier cosine/sine transform and Fourier transform.

Comment: Everything looks okay. The inverse Fourier transform will be $\mathcal{F}_c+i\mathcal{F}_s$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts So we can say that the Fourier cosine transform of an even function is equivalent to the Fourier transform of the same function?

Comment: @Stuart-JamesBurney : Yes. The Fourier transform of an even function $f$ is an even function $\mathcal{F}f$ whose restriction to $[0,\infty)$ is the same as the Fourier cosine transform of $f$ on $[0,\infty)$. That's another way to put it.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts That's so cool. Following on from my proof, does this mean the Fourier transform of an odd function $f$ is an odd function $\mathcal{F}f$ whose restriction to $[0,\infty)$ is the same as the Fourier sine transform of $-if$ on $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: @Stuart-JamesBurney Yes, that's it